# avoiding layout reloading in ruby on rails project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In ruby on rails , I want to load page data dynamically. But that time i don't want to refresh or load layout page, only body should render.I am having two pages and when i switch from one page to another then the layout page data should not be reload, only another page data should load.

Comment: [`Talk is cheap. Show me the code.`](http://izquotes.com/quote/273528)

Comment: It is a basic concept. In every rails applications, we have layout folder. within that we have home.html.erb layout page for all home controller view files. whenever i run any  page, it will load the layout page also. but i don't want to reload the layout page for all pages. how to avoid this.

Comment: i tried to use ajax calls. but it need partial files. but i don't want make all files as partial. give me suggestions plz, in someother way.

Comment: `render layout: false`

Comment: yeah, it doesn't load the layout. but i need to avoid  RELOADing of layout page. Actually i want the layout, but no need to reload (layout) again again for evry page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches you could take here.

1. Turbolinks - This will refresh a little more than what it sounds like you want, but if you are doing this kind of thing a lot, you may want to take a read. https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
2. Manually using ajax requests using the following approach:

A. Add the following gem to your Gemfile
https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

B. Include this in your JS. e.g. In your JavaScript file, load it by including the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

C: Update your link to include remote: true:

```
<%= link_to 'New page', page_path, remote: true %>
```

D: Add a respond to js in your controller. e.g.:

```
  def action_name
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

E: Create a new file named action_name.js.erb in your views. You can then place any javascript code within this file. So you can target a specific element on the page and replace it with a partial.

e.g.

```
$("#id_of_element_on_page").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'page_content', locals: { project: @project })) %>");
```

That's pretty much it, when you now click on the link, you app should send an ajax request and you should get the rendered javascript in the response which in turn should update the element on the page you wish to replace.